# Grails: Get context path in BootStrap.groovy

Tags: java, grails, servlets

How can I get the context path in the BootStrap.groovy file of a Grails application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't you do:

```
class BootStrap {
  def init = { servletContext ->
    println "$servletContext.contextPath"
  }
  def destroy = {
  }
}
```